# Обрабатывает ли плагин LiveEdit таблицы стилей?

Tags: phpstorm, плагин

Установил себе плагин LiveEdit и расширение JetBrains IDE Support. Все внесенные изменения в html файле я моментально вижу в браузере. А вот при редактировании таблиц стилей SASS/CSS никакого Live Coding не наблюдается. Можно это исправить? И вообще: предусмотрено ли, чтобы плагин LiveEdit отслеживал изменения во всех файлах, касающихся верстки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, безусловно, Live Edit должен отслеживать изменения в stylesheet файлах. Но, во-первых, для этого опцию `Update` (`Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit`) нужно выставить в `Auto`; во-вторых, текущий Live Edit плагин не совместим с PHPStorm 10.0.3 ([WEB-19756](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19756)), поэтому обновление страницы при изменении CSS не работает

Comment: Понятно. Настройки то у меня выставлены были. А вот PhpStorm версии 10.0.3. А на предыдущей 10-ой версии работает?

Comment: можно попробовать - возможно, предыдущая версия (2.0.22.143 - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=idea&updateId=22988) будет работать с предыдущим PHPstorm...

Comment: Спасибо, попробую) Надеюсь плагин быстро обновят, исправив баг. Уж очень он удобен. Пока что пользуюсь LiveReload

Comment: Обновили плагин полчаса назад, но он все так же не работает(( Отписался в той теме, что проверил их плагин и он все так же не работает при редактировании таблиц стилей.

Comment: да, ьам опять нет полной совместимости, я переоткрыла https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19756